# How to use flag with scipy.optimize fsolve

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is a simplified version of code. When run with no flag, I get results.
But, when I use flags it throws errors. I need to run this code through fsolve. The code has been simplified.

**Error:**     The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

price = np.array([39, 34, 29, 25, 21])
S     = np.repeat(300, len(price)) 
flag  = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])

def Val(S, flag = 0):
    p = 4 
    if   flag == 0: p = S * flag
    elif flag == 1: p = S * flag
    return p 

val = lambda x: Val(S, flag) - price
print fsolve(val, np.repeat(35, len(S)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem:

```
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.optimize import fsolve

    price = np.array([39, 34, 29, 25, 21])
    S     = np.repeat(300, len(price)) 
    flag  = np.array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])

    def Val(S, flag = 0):
        return np.where(flag, S + price, S - price )

    val = lambda x: Val(S, flag) - price
    print fsolve(val, np.repeat(35, len(S)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `flag` in `Val` is a scalar, but the `flag` variable  you declared above is an array. When `flag` is a scalar, `flag == 0` will also be a scalar (either `True` or `False`), and your `if` and `elif` statements will make sense.

However, if `flag` is an array, the output of `flag == 0` will be a boolean array with the same shape as `flag`. In your case it will be `np.array([False, False, True, False, False])`. In the array case, `if flag == 0` is ambiguous, since there may be more than one element in the array that can be true or false. What if (as in your example) some of the elements in the array are true and some are false - should we execute the `if` branch or the `elif` branch?

In your case it wouldn't even matter, since you are performing exactly the same calculation in both cases.

Comment: It's unclear from your example what your intent is. The first argument to `fsolve` needs to be a function that returns a scalar, and `fsolve` seeks to find the parameter(s) `x` that make this value equal to 0. However in your case when `flag` is an array then the result of `Val` will also be an array. The optimization problem is ill-defined if your function outputs more than one value - what if some change in `x` increases the value of the first element in the output array but reduces the value of the second?